# different roles in Django: show different content in web page

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm using Django to develop an webapp, I created different roles of users, for example `CunstomerUser, GoodUser, Admin`...etc.

Now I want to show them different things when they login. For example, when they open a popup, the `CustomerUser` will see a textarea field for commenting and for the `Admin` he will see other things he can do.

I found that we can do it in the `template` level, like:

```
{% if request.user.is_superuser %}
.... superuser content
{% else %}
.... non-superuser content
{% endif %}
```

But how can I do in the javascript file which is used by this `template`? Cause I want to show them the different functions depends on their roles. For example I want to determine the role in the `example.js` which is included in the template:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
...
</html>
```

The current solution that I found is to create a variable global javascript in the template so that all the javascipt files can use:

```
<script>
 var userType = '{{user.get_usertype}}';
</scirpt>
```

But is their a better way to do this? the variable global is not so good to use I think...maybe I used a dump pattern design. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I think the most proper way is to check user role in view and thus render different template for it. If your templates got many common content, you can use Django's `{% include %}` and `{% block %}` tags to follow DRY principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong but you could still use django template syntax in javascript, because django template is evaluated before the page is loaded, so it still works by hiding/showing the portion that's relevant to the specific user:

```
<script>
{% if request.user.is_superuser %}
    var userType = 'superuser';
{% else %}
    var userType = 'normaluser';
{% endif %}
</script>
```

The above code block doesn't have to be global, it could happen anywhere within your template file. You will always get just one definition of `userType` in this case.

**Edit:**

Well, the point of avoid global variables is because they might get changed by other functions so the values might messed up. However if you define pseudo-constants then you should be fine.

Javascript doesn't have constants but you could use any html with an id to achieve that:

html:

```
<p style="display: none;" class="identity" id="{% if request.user.is_superuser %}superuser{% else %}normaluser{% endif %}"></p>
```

example.js:

```
var user_role = $('p.identity').attr('id');
```

One caveat is that you need to load your `example.js` at the end of the template, otherwise it will load before the html loads, thus couldn't find the element.

Comment: Sorry for not saying it clearly...can you see my update question above?Thanks

Comment: No you are right, you can use templates + javascript this way it just get's horribly complicated sometimes. Anyway +1

Comment: I edited my answer, it's a little convoluted, but see if it makes sense.